# Ansible "ansible_python_interpreter" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, influxdb

I want to instal influxdb and configuration with ansible.
File copy and influxdb configuration is ok
But creating database and user create section is give a "ansible_python_interpreter" error.

I searched this error and tried something but I can't solve this problem with myself

This is my ansible hosts file

```
[loadbalancer]
lb      ansible_host=192.168.255.134

[loadbalancer:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python3"
#ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"
#ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/libexec/platform-python"
```

This is my yaml file

```
# influxdb install and configuration

---
  - hosts: lb
    become: true
    tasks:
      - name: Copy Repo Files
        copy:
          src: ./files/influxdb.j2
          dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/influxdb.repo
          remote_src: no
      - name: Install Influxdb
        yum:
          name: influxdb
          state: latest
        notify:
             influxdb_ok
      - name: Crete Database
        community.general.influxdb_database:
          hostname: 192.168.255.134
          database_name: deneme
      - name: Create User
        community.general.influxdb_user:
          user_name: deneme_user
          user_password: deneme123

    handlers:
      - name: Start Influx Service
        service:
          name: influxdb
          state: started
          enabled: yes
        listen: influxdb_ok
```

I was tried to install python3 remote vm(lb).
I was tried to change interpreter parameters.
I was tried to install requests module with pip3.

```
[root@centos8 influx]# ansible-playbook influxdb.yaml -K
BECOME password:

PLAY [lb] ***********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [lb]

TASK [Copy Repo Files] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [lb]

TASK [Install Influxdb] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [lb]

TASK [Crete Database] ***********************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
fatal: [lb]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (requests) on loadbalancer.servicepark.local's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
lb                         : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I was tried to install requests module and currently ansible version

Right now my ansible machine versions

```
[root@centos8 influx]# python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[root@centos8 influx]# ansible --version
ansible 2.10.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

lb vm's versions

```
[root@loadbalancer ~]# influx --version
InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.2
[root@loadbalancer ~]# python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: There's a python module missing (`requests`). Your should run a [`pip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) pre_task that ensures all required modules are installed.

Comment: @KlausD. I added now and tried and It's work but still got the same result. "- name: Install pip
         pip:
           name: requests"

Comment: Please note that the module must be installed on the target (i.e. `lb`) and in the correct version of python (i.e. 3.6.8 and not 2.7 if you have both installed).

Comment: @Zeitounator it's installed. requests version is 2.24.0 and there is only installed python3

Comment: What's does `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip list` return **on that host**?

Comment: @thargalin then you have to find out why you think it is installed and why ansible thinks it is not. Hint: at this guess game, machine is right 99.99999% of the time.

Comment: @KlausD. on host "requests (2.24.0) " and remote machine "requests (2.24.0)"

Comment: @Zeitounator Actually it's work but it's not work in ansible-playbook. For example, If I send a "ansible lb -m ping" command it's it's working. When I send a "ansible lb -m ping -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3'" it's work again!

Comment: @Zeitounator but there is different between to output. If I send without interpreter parameter ansible add a output this line ""discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python""

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Comment: It's work! But I have very big mistake. I control requirement for influxdb_user module. It's just want to influx > 0.9 version but influxdb_database want influx 0.9 > and < 1.2.4. I change version and install influxdb module remote host with pip (like request). It's wrok :) Thank you @Zeitounator

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 3 ways to solve this problem if you encounter it on your remote host:

1. Set ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3 variable for all hosts that have python3 installed by default
2. Install Python 2 using Ansible’s raw module
3. Symlink /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/bin/python using Ansible’s raw module.

All 3 options can be done in Ansible, without sshing into the host.

**example**

```
- name: misc task on ubuntu 18.04 instance
  hosts: "*"
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_host
```

Option 3 - Symlink /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3 using Ansible’s raw module
Another option in a similar vein to option 2 is to use the raw module to “symlink” /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.

With a bit of shell magic, we can fashion a command to do this conditionally based on whether either of the files exist using conditionals:

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/python3 ] && [ ! -f /usr/bin/python ]; then 
  ln --symbolic /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; 
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
- name: Install requests python package
  pip:
    name: requests
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.